# Filter WP category by a custom field called town, but orderby town alphabetically not working

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have `archive-jobs.php` and it is filtering Jobs by a category, eg `'Developer'`.
This works fine, but, the issue is it's not filtering the results in alphabetical order by my custom field called `'town'`.

It's not really filtering them in any logical order either.

This is my code:

```
<?php

$args = array( 
    'posts_per_page' => -1 ,
    'post_type' => 'jobs',
    'cat' => get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) )->term_id,
    'meta_key'      => 'valid_until_date', //ACF date field
    'meta_query'    => array( 
        array(
        'key' => 'valid_until_date', 
        'value' => date('Y-m-d'), 
        'compare' => '>=', 
        'type' => 'DATE'
    )),
    'meta_key'          => 'town',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'             => 'ASC'
);
    
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
?>
```

and attached is the way the field is set up within the plugin 'Custom Fields'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`orderby => "metavalue"` will use the metadata key at `meta_key` to order posts.

You have two instances of `meta_key` used in your query - you should remove `'meta_key' => 'valid_until_date'` for it to recognize you want to order by town instead.

Comment: so how can i order by town and then valid until date?

Comment: I'll edit this post later, but you can use string keys in  `meta_query` e.g. `'meta_query' => ['town' => [...], 'valid_date'  => ['...']]`, and then reference these in `orderby`: e.g. `orderby => ['town' => 'ASC', 'vald_date' => 'DESC']` - See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters for more information.